# How to check If a view has been touched?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-video-player

I'm using a third party video player in my app. The library provides enough functionalities like scroll video, pause, play video etc. And all those features will auto-hide after a few seconds. I need a few more controls over the player. So I put a toolbar on it ( It consists of the back, favorite, share buttons ). I need to enable this toolbar only If someone clicks on the player or even taps on it. And it must hide after a few seconds like the video player's controller. I tried using this,

```
  youtubePlayerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                LogUtils.LOGE("youtubePlayerView.setOnClick", "called");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But in vain. Nothing is happening. 
I want to detect If the user has clicked or tapped on the player.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
 public void onClickHandler(View v)
           {
               switch (v.getId()) {
                   case R.id.youtubePlayerView:
                            //Player Clicked
                       break;
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
youtubePlayerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // enable toolbar here!
    }
});
```

Comment: tried this too... 
But for some reason it's not working at all.

Comment: Thats weird. Pls include your layout for your player. And which player library did you use?

Comment: '<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_video_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">




        <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/transparent_toolbar"/>


    </FrameLayout>' 
'

Comment: your toolbar is on top of your playerview. could it be filtering the click events?